# I couldnt find the fault in my code for login page test with selenium java

Tags: java, exception, selenium-webdriver

```
package automation;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MainPage {
private final WebDriver driver;

public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver; 

}

public MainPage loginAs(String username, String password)  {
    driver.get("URL");        
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("username");

    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.className("login")).click(); 

   return new MainPage(driver);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.genko.driver",         "C:\\Users\\Guest01\\Desktop\\chromedriver");
    MainPage login = new MainPage(new ChromeDriver());
    login.loginAs("qa@gmail.com", "123456");
}
}
```

I tried to test login function for the web site and wrote above code for it. However,
I couldnt find the error on it. Can someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Your code doesnt have error, is this your problem??

Comment: what's not working or compiling here? @E.Dogan

Comment: `driver.get("URL"); ` doesn't for now has a url where you might want to perform the login as the method name suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things wrong with your code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.genko.driver",         "C:\\Users\\Guest01\\Desktop\\chromedriver");
```

Should be (make sure the chromedriver is the correct file, the windows version usually has an .exe extension.)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Guest01\\Desktop\\chromedriver");
```

You also should navigate the url of the page you want to test using

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://[enter url here]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write the "gecko driver" instead of "genko driver".